# Updating UITableView section headers dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I would like to download and update custom section headers asynchronously, but I just can't find a way to do it. I currently make custom `UIView`s in the following method:

[tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a)

I could download data synchronously from there but that would temporally freeze the UI, which is not user friendly at all.

---

**More details**:

My tableview is based on Core Data, and the downloaded data can be stored in a binary property of my image entity. Therefore I checked whether changes could be detected, and there is a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method that almost does what I want:

[controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate/controller%3adidChangeSection%3aatIndex%3aforChangeType%3a)

But unfortunately it doesn't support section headers updates (deletes  / inserts only)...

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you not just call:

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

after you have received new data and updated the CoreData DB.

Comment: Thank you Linasses, I can't believe I overlooked this method. It indeed solved my problem.

Comment: Be careful this will trump any other table animations in that section at the time you use it. I have a bug in with apple on this 7896719.  It would be nicety just have a call to refresh the headers or footers

Comment: @BrentPriddy any news on that bug report? I've just hit the same problem: the table animation looks lovely and smooth, but calling reloadSections destroys it - would be great to just refresh the headers somehow.

Comment: 7896719 is the real issue, mine was closed as duplicate... So I wont be able to tell you the status of the real issue 7896719.

Answer (score 5):

Also an option if you are using FetchedResultsControllers:

in the subroutine:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
```

add this line somewhere (assuming you have declared the variable in the header...):

```
    sectionToUpdate = newIndexPath.section;
```

Then in:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

add something like this at the end:

```
if (sectionToUpdate != -1) {
    [yourtableview         beginUpdates];
    [yourtableview         reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionToUpdate] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [yourtableview         endUpdates];
    sectionToUpdate = -1;
}
```

Should save you from doing an entire reload of the table.

Comment: This method may fail if more than one section is inserted during a single Fetched Results update cycle and more than one of those updated sections is visible on screen when all updates are complete. This is because only the last section changed will be reloaded. Before you try making an index set of changed sections, let me say there isn't any point. Calling reloadData() on the table reloads all cells on screen. Reloading all visible sections will have exactly the same visual effect. The trick is to avoid making repeated saves to the MOC so that all updates come through at once.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation: (or even reloadData) will work, but if that isn't good for you for other reasons (as it wasn't for me, I didn't want the current text field to resign first responder), you can keep references to all of the headerViews and then update them directly when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain/obtain a pointer to the section header(s), and you update it, what happens?

Also, what happens when you use the the methods you mentioned. For example: in `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` call your `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` (using the table view and section from controller:didChangeSection:) and alter the view as necessary.

Comment: the controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType method gets called only when a section is inserted or removed so I can't use it in my case apparently. I will try implementing an NSDictionary that keeps a reference to those header views (sectionNb as key and headerView as value). Is it something like that that you suggested?